# WSL fuser command not working

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using WSL Ubuntu

```
$ /bin/fuser
Cannot open /proc/net/unix: No such file or directory
```

I also tried as root user by first issuing:

```
sudo su
```

It is not like I intentionally deleted that path.

Is fuser supposed to work out of the box or is there additional config needed? Or do I need to do a complete reinstall?

I've searched all over so now I am turning to you all - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quote from the article
[Initial Evaluation of the Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://nullprogram.com/blog/2017/11/30/):

> Really, there’s almost no device emulation at all and `/proc` is pretty empty. You won’t see hard drives or removable media under `/dev`, nor will you see USB devices like webcams and joysticks. A lot of the useful things you might do on a Linux system aren’t available under WSL.

The answer is that `/proc` is an interface that needs to be implemented by
Microsoft, since it needs to be implemented using Windows API calls.
Evidently, Microsoft hasn't gone yet to the effort of implementing all
these virtual folders, and it's unknown if this will ever be done.

Until Microsoft does this development, all utilities that use unimplemented
interfaces will fail.

You will need to find alternative utilities that only use implemented
interfaces, or access yourself the files containing the source data.

Answer (score 0):

Installing WSL2 will fix this issue and the `/proc` directory will be fully populated.